Codegen Sympy computing matrix of expressions
I have a set of matrices with sympy expressions. I succeed to generate a .f90 file and used it properly in another code but I have still two problems.
File generated by codegen. (The real expressions inside the matrices are far more complicated ,these are just for test purpose)
subroutine matA11(Gamma1, g, p0, rho0, yml, out_8665343569832042533)
implicit none
REAL*8, intent(in) :: Gamma1
REAL*8, intent(in) :: g
REAL*8, intent(in) :: p0
REAL*8, intent(in) :: rho0
REAL*8, intent(in) :: yml
REAL*8, intent(out), dimension(1:4, 1:4) :: out_8665343569832042533

out_8665343569832042533(1, 1) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(2, 1) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(3, 1) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(4, 1) = rho0*yml/(Gamma1*p0)
out_8665343569832042533(1, 2) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(2, 2) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(3, 2) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(4, 2) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(1, 3) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(2, 3) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(3, 3) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(4, 3) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(1, 4) = g*yml
out_8665343569832042533(2, 4) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(3, 4) = 0
out_8665343569832042533(4, 4) = 0

end subroutine

subroutine matA21(drdmu, dyml, g, m, mu, r, ymlp, &
      out_825899070853517470)
implicit none
REAL*8, intent(in) :: drdmu
REAL*8, intent(in) :: dyml
REAL*8, intent(in) :: g
REAL*8, intent(in) :: m
REAL*8, intent(in) :: mu
REAL*8, intent(in) :: r
REAL*8, intent(in) :: ymlp
REAL*8, intent(out), dimension(1:4, 1:3) :: out_825899070853517470

out_825899070853517470(1, 1) = -drdmu*dyml*g*mu**2/r + drdmu*dyml*g/r
out_825899070853517470(2, 1) = 0
out_825899070853517470(3, 1) = 0
out_825899070853517470(4, 1) = 0
out_825899070853517470(1, 2) = -drdmu*g*m*ymlp/r
out_825899070853517470(2, 2) = 0
out_825899070853517470(3, 2) = 0
out_825899070853517470(4, 2) = 0
out_825899070853517470(1, 3) = 0
out_825899070853517470(2, 3) = 0
out_825899070853517470(3, 3) = 0
out_825899070853517470(4, 3) = 0


How can I change the type inside codegen (It seems possible by reading the documentation but I can't figure out how to deal with it). I want double precision real numbers
for each matrix, the f90 file needs different arguments + the name of the matrix for intent(out), how can I create a list of arguments even if they are not used all inside the computation of the matrix ?

I have something like that generated and I would like to call in that way : CALL matA11(all_the_variables_in_the_f90_file,name_matrix) and same call for the second one with just changing name matA21(all_the_variables_in_the_f90_file,name_matrix)
Right now, I have to specify correctly each argument in the subroutine, but the user should not do that.
